# d3 histogram already binned

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Truth is, while I'm trying to make a histogram, maybe d3's histogram isn't the proper function to use as I already have data binned.  That is, my dataset looks like this:

```
time-in-seconds : count
```

where each entry is an hour.

i.e.

```
{ "1380736800" : 14,
  "1380740400" : 3,
  "1380744000" : 14,
   and so on
}
```

in human readable format:

```
{ "Oct 2, 2013 11:00AM" : 14,
  "Oct 2, 2013 12:00PM" : 3,
  "Oct 2, 2013  1:00PM  : 14,
   and so on
}
```

Is d3's histogram the right tool to use?  Specifically, d3.layout.histogram?

Comment: In short, no, you do not need `d3.layout.histogram`, unless you want to `rebin` your data. Are you facing problems in any particular instance or in implementing something which will be more amenable to the data format returned by `d3.layout.histogram`?

Comment: Thanks, @musically_ut.. No specific problems, just that I want the end result to be a histogram (in the technical sense of the distribution of data in bins) so naturally I looked to d3.layout.histogram but I'm realizing that since my data is already binned I should probably go simpler.

Comment: All you should need to do is draw the rectangles for the bins.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff.. I'm in the process of implementing that.  'good to know I'm on the right track.

Comment: Say, @LarsKotthoff, if I wanted to re-bin the data from hours to days or months, would you _then_ suggest using d3.layout.histogram?

Comment: Say, @musically_ut, if I wanted to re-bin the data from hours to days or months, would you _then_ suggest using d3.layout.histogram?

Comment: Yes, then you should be able to use it without problems.

Comment: either of y'all wanna answer this?